# How to test InAppPurchase In itunes connect

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In My application we add InAppPurchase application with MKStoreObserver.h and .m file and MKStoreManager.h and .m file in my app.   we want to test my this as transaction is done or not how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the sandbox. You can then do transaction within your app without actually having to pay for them. I would suggest you start by reading the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW1) on Apple's iPhone Dev Center.

Comment: I read that document but i am not understanding how to test what result will show when test.